# Optimise Linq-to-Sql mapping with one to many lookup

Tags: linq-to-sql, database-design, optimization, orm, entity-relationship

I'm having problems optimising data lookup with the following data structure:

```
Order
----- 
Id 
Customer 
Date 
... etc


OrderStatus
------
Id
OrderId
Date
UpdatedBy
StatusTypeId
...etc
```

This is causing me a headache on the **Order List** page, which basically shows a list of `Orders`. Each **Order Summary** in the list shows a bunch of fields from `Order` and the current `OrderStatus`, i.e. the `OrderStatus` with the latest `Date` which is linked to the `Order`.

```
Order List
-------------------------------------------------------
Order Id | Customer     | Order Date  | CurrentStatus |
-------------------------------------------------------
1        | Someone      |  1.10.2010  | Completed     |
-------------------------------------------------------
2        | Someone else | 12.10.2010  | In Progress   |
-------------------------------------------------------
3        | Whoever      | 17.10.2010  | On Hold       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, say I want to list all orders from this year. My Repository fetches the `Order` objects

`var orders = _repository.GetAllOrdersSinceDate(dt);`

and now I end up with something like

```
foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    OrderSummary summary = new OrderSummary();
    summary.Customer = order.Customer;
    summary.Date = order.Date;
    // ...etc

    // problem here!!
    summary.OrderStatus = order.OrderStatus
                .OrderByDescending(s => status.Date).First();
}
```

So what I end up with is a `SELECT` statement on `Order` and then a further `SELECT` statement on `OrderStatus` for each `Order` returned.

So to show the summary of all records for this year is requiring around 20,000 individual SQL queries and taking many minutes to load.

Is there any neat way to fix this problem?

I'm considering re-writing the database to hold the **current** `OrderStatus` in the `Order` table, so I end up with something like

```
Order
----- 
Id 
Customer 
Date 
CurrentStatusTypeId
CurrentStatusDate
CurrentStatusUpdatedBy
...etc


OrderStatusHistory
------
Id
OrderId
Date
UpdatedBy
StatusTypeId
...etc
```

which is the only way I can see to solve the problem but seems a pretty nasty solution.

Whats the best way forward here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't denormalize your database model to solve your problem. This will only make things worse. You can fix this by writing a service method that returns a list of data transfer objects (DTO) instead of the LINQ to SQL entities. For instance, the service method might look like this:

```
public OrderSummary[] GetOrderSummariesSinceDate(DateTime d)
{
    return (
        from order in this.context.Orders
        where order.Date >= d
        let lastStatus = (
            from status in order.OrderStatusses
            orderby status.Date descending
            select status).First()
        select new OrderSummary
        {
            OrderId = order.Id,
            CustomerName = order.Customer.Name,
            Date = order.Date,
            OrderStatus = lastStatus.StatusType.Name
        }).ToArray();    
}
```

Note the following:

- This code will execute as a single SQL query in the database.
- This method will return an object that contains just the data that the client needs, but nothing more. No `Customer` object, no `OrderStatus` object.
- By calling `ToArray` we ensure that the database is queried at this point and it is not deferred.

These three points ensure that the performance is maximized and allows the service layer to stay in control over what is executed to the database.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It kinda helps and yet kinda doesn't help. I know I need to do something like this but it's full of problems. My Order object lives in the domain layer. My OrderSummary object is part of a ViewModel in my presentation layer. My OrderRepository doesn't even know OrderSummary exists. My OrderRepository wraps a generic Linq respository which gives me pretty limited control. I am using DTO's, but I still can't return much except an Order object (this is my own Order class, not the Linq generated class) with a GetCurrentStatus() method.

Comment: You can move `OrderSummary` to the service layer, or define a DTO their and map it to your ViewModel in your presentation layer. You need to work with DTOs at this level to get good performance. If your repository is to limited, perhaps you should take a different approach there. For instance, implement IQueryable<T> on your repositories. Look here for inspiration: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataLoadOptions object as follows:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext
DataLoadOptions ds = new DataLoadOptions();
ds.LoadWith<OrderStatus>(c => c.Orders);
db.LoadOptions = ds;
```

Then when you run your query it should prefetch the OrderStatus table

Comment: This does improve performance, but there's still room for improvement. `LoadWith` will fetch all `OrderStatus` records of each `Order` from the database, while only the last `OrderStatus` per order is needed.